# y axis breaks doesn't work when ggplot `geom_density_ridges`

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(Species=as.integer(Species)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species, group = Species)) + 
  geom_density_ridges()
```

Above script works well and output as below:
[image]

But when I add breaks to y axis, the breaks disappear.

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(Species=as.integer(Species)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species, group = Species)) + 
  scale_y_discrete(limit=c(0,30),breaks = seq(0,30,1))+
  geom_density_ridges()
```

[image]

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a (continuous) numeric *y* axis, you need to use `scale_y_continuous()` (which takes number breaks) rather than `scale_y_discrete()` (which takes a character vector of breaks). I'll use your example, however, it doesn't make much sense to me as you're converting `Species` to integers...:

```
# working nonsense
iris %>% 
    mutate(Species=as.integer(Species)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species, group = Species)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(limit=c(0,30),breaks = seq(0,30,1))+
    geom_density_ridges()
```

This works as you probably want (integer breaks are displayed), but, as I say, it seems to be a nonsense.

`geom_density_ridges()` is used rather for displaying  multiple density plots with categorical data on y axis, like this:

```
iris %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species)) + 
    geom_density_ridges()
```